# WordPress : How to get your related posts with thumbnails to show up in 1 horizontal row in genesis

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I have a script that makes a related list with thumbnails to show up in wordpress(Version 4.1) under the framework genesis.

Now I can't seem to figure out how to place them all in 1 row.

I want it to look like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/UHYmi.jpg

However, at the moment it looks like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/9UKxL.jpg

The code:

PHP Code in a site specific plugin:

```
<?php

/*
  Plugin Name: *mysite Related posts
  Description: add related posts with thumbnails to your posts
 */
/* Start Adding Functions Below this Line */

/* Display related posts in Genesis based on Tags */

function related_posts_tags() {
    if (is_single()) {
        global $post;
        $count = 0;
        $postIDs = array($post->ID);
        $related = '';
        $tags = wp_get_post_tags($post->ID);
        foreach ($tags as $tag) {
            $tagID[] = $tag->term_id;
        }
        $args = array(
            'tag__in' => $tagID,
            'post__not_in' => $postIDs,
            'showposts' => 5,
            'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1,
            'tax_query' => array(
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'post_format',
                    'field' => 'slug',
                    'terms' => array(
                        'post-format-link',
                        'post-format-status',
                        'post-format-aside',
                        'post-format-quote'
                    ),
                    'operator' => 'NOT IN'
                )
            )
        );
        $tag_query = new WP_Query($args);
        if ($tag_query->have_posts()) {
            while ($tag_query->have_posts()) {
                $tag_query->the_post();
                $img = genesis_get_image() ? genesis_get_image(array('size' => 'thumbnail')) : '<img src="' . get_bloginfo('stylesheet_directory') . '/images/related.png" alt="' . get_the_title() . '" />';
                $related .= '<li><a href="' . get_permalink() . '" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to' . get_the_title() . '">' . $img . get_the_title() . '</a></li>';
                $postIDs[] = $post->ID;
                $count++;
            }
        }
        if ($related) {
            printf('<div><h3>Related Posts</h3><ul>%s</ul></div>', $related);
        }
        wp_reset_query();
    }
}

add_action('genesis_after_entry_content', 'related_posts_tags');


/* Stop Adding Functions Below this Line */
?>
```

This is the .css

```
.related-posts {
overflow: hidden;
margin: 0 0 30px;
font-size: 14px;
line-height: 15px;
}

.related-list li {
  float: left;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0 10px 0 0;
  text-align: right;
  width: 170px;
}

.related-list img,{
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #D8D4D0;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

I'm really out of any idea's where to go with this.
The first and second screenshots have identical .css and .php

Any tips or fixes are more than welcome!

Comment: Are you sure you are using your css?

Comment: It is placed like this within the style.css under \wp-content\themes\mytheme\style.css

All the other .css codes in that file seem to be working just fine.
The code for .related-posts .related-list img and .related-list li Doesn't seem to work at all.

I got no clue how to make it work though...(If you need any other information, feel free to let me know and I'll be happy to post it)

Comment: Can you remove the cache of your browser?

Comment: I have deleted the cash in both my browsers. (Chrome and Firefox).
No change whatsoever. 

Also cleared the cache from the website's site(Wordfence falcon cache) just to be sure. also no effect.

Comment: Does anybody here have any idea what to do with this/how to get it to work?

I've been fighting with this thing for weeks now....